# Can somebody explain clearly what this code does? - OpenGL & SDL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

In general I want to find out what the opengl functions do in this piece of code such as glOrtho();.

I have searched around trying to find out in good detail what they mean and do but I have trouble finding any good explanations of the code. The SDL code I am fine with.

I was also wondering if anybody could describe well for me gltranslatef();

```
bool init_GL()
{
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    //Set projection
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1 );
    //Initialize modelview matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    //If there was any errors
    if( glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR )
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool init()
{
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0 )
        return false;
    //Create Window
    if( SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_OPENGL ) == NULL )
        return false;
    //Initialize OpenGL
    if( init_GL() == false )
        return false;
    //Set caption
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "OpenGL Test", NULL );
    return true;
}
```

This code is from the lazyfoo tutorials but it doesn't describe a lot of the code.

Greatly appreciated to anybody who can help.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml, http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTranslate.xml

Comment: http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics

Answer (score 7):

I'll break it down for you:

```
bool init_GL()
{
```

This function, init_GL I mean, is bad style. All what it does, actually belonged into the drawing function

```
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
```

glClearColor sets the color the framebuffer will be filled with (cleard) when calling glClear with the GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT set.

```
    //Set projection
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
```

glMatrixMode switches the matrix upon which OpenGL matrix manipulation functions have an effect. OpenGL knows the matrices "Projection", "Modelview", "Texture" and "Color". The last two are rarely touched.

```
    glLoadIdentity();
```

Load Identity will put a identity matrix on the current position in the matrix stack. A identity matrix, multiplied with a vector, will yield the very same vector.

```
    glOrtho( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1 );
```

glOrtho multiplies the identity matrix with a [orthographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) matrix. Some projections, like orthographic or affine perspective can be described by a linear trasformation. Linear transformations can be expressed by matrices. In some way you may think the projection matrix as kind of the "lens" of the OpenGL camera (there is no camera in OpenGL though!).

```
    //Initialize modelview matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
```

Here the matrix mode is switched to the Modelview matrix. The Modelview matrix is used for both placing objects in the world (model-) and moving the world relative to the "camera" (-view, hence modelview).

```
    //If there was any errors
    if( glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR )
    {
        return false;
    }
```

This error checking code is wrong. In OpenGL you've to call glGetError in a loop until it returns GL_NO_ERROR.

```
    return true;
}

bool init()
{

    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Initializes the SDL library, so it can be used.

```
    //Create Window
    if( SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_OPENGL ) == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }
```

SDL_SetVideoMode creates a window (if in a windowed graphics system, if operating on the naked framebuffer it will do like the name suggests, setting the video mode), maybe change the video mode to another display resolution (if in fullscreen mode), and create an OpenGL context.

```
    //Initialize OpenGL
    if( init_GL() == false )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Set caption
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "OpenGL Test", NULL );
```

Finally this sets the window title.

```
    return true;
}
```

Nothing gets rendered so far. Also this program lacks a event loop, so a window will appear only flashing on the screen, that disappear and the program terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can say that both glOrtho and glTranslate produce matrices that are multiplied with the current rendering matrix. The final rendering matrix will be used to transform all vertices in your scene which will effect lighting, culling, perspective. So, in the end, all these matrices controls the way objects are rendered to your screen.

Using these (together with a multitude of other matrix functions) you can scale, rotate, translate objects in your scene and control if you should use orthogonal (parallel) projection or perspective projection. You can read up on these here:

[glOrtho:](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)

> glOrtho describes a transformation that produces a parallel projection.
>               The current matrix (see glMatrixMode) is multiplied by this matrix
>               and the result replaces the current matrix

[gltranslatef](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTranslate.xml):

> glTranslate produces a translation by (x, y, z). 
>               The current matrix
>               (see
>               glMatrixMode)
>               is multiplied by this translation matrix

But I think that if you really want to learn OpenGL, and have fun doing so, follow tutorials and follow up with theory, graphical programming is a bit of a world on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a real beginner with OpenGL. I had the 1999 book of "OpenGL Super Bible" which explains everything very nicely (See http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/) and it helped me a lot in learning OpenGL.

I could explain `glOrtho` and `glTranslatef` to you, but in a day you are going to need an explanation on `glRotatef`, `gluPerspective`, `glBegin`, `glClear`, `glFlush`, `glVertex3f` etc etc and you can't keep asking those questions here.

So my suggestion is to go buy a nice OpenGL book (like the OpenGL super bible) and start learning it by the book.

You could also take a look at [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Opengl#Legacy_OpenGL_1.x), for example on the transformations section, but I haven't read it myself so I don't know if it's good enough. This part is on early versions of OpenGL though and is only good for starting to get the idea. In modern OpenGL, you wouldn't be programming like that.

One word of advice, in modern OpenGL a lot of common practices in OpenGL 1.x are deprecated. If you searched google and ended up in NeHe's website, remember that what you learn in that website, you might want to forget about when you move on to newer versions of OpenGL.